# Splunk alert scheduling to stop running script on particular times

Tags: alert, splunk, job-scheduling, splunk-query

I have two splunk scripts one to Run at 30 minutes and another one at 120 minutes between 00.00 to 06.00.

Now I would like to hold 30 minutes script not to run between this timeframe. How to do this one from splunk.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 30-minute script to run on a cron schedule rather than every thirty minutes.  Use `0/30 7-23 * * *` as the schedule.  This tells the script to run every 30 minutes from 0700 until 23:30.  If that cron string doesn't work, try `0,30 7-23 * * *`.

Comment: Hi Team,

I have created a couple of alerts. The first one is running every 30 minutes from Mon-Friday, and another one is running at 00.00 to 06.00 every 2 hours.

What I want is for the 30-minute job to pause or stop while the 2-hour one is running, then have the 30-minute job resume after the 2-hour one is complete. Or, is there another way to put the 30-minute job on hold?

Here is the schedule I used for 30M:

 - 0,30 0-6,12-23 * * 1-5
And this one for 2H:

 120M - 0 2-6/2 * * * 
But I still I see some alerts were triggered during 120 minutes.
Kindly help - it is a bit urgent

Comment: Also how to cover the last 30 minutes, for example, 0,30 0-6,12-23 ** 1-5 which will give the results till 6.30 and 23.30, but how about the last 30minutes clash how we can retain the transaction between those timings